# How can I get android View kind programmatically?

Tags: android, view

I want to get View object programmatically. 
But, not fixed View kind, like.. RadioButton..Button..
I only want to know View kind for View's properties.
Is it possible?

Please see this :

```
String idString = "view_from_xml_id";
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(idString, "id", getPackageName());
View iDontKnowWhat = findViewById(id);
```

The [iDontKnowWhat] view object is Just View.
But, I want to cast this [iDontKnowWhat] view object to RadioButton, Button, EditText...Case by Case.

I want like this :

```
String idString = "view_from_xml_id";
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(idString, "id", getPackageName());
View iDontKnowWhat = findViewById(id);

if(iDontKnowWhat == RadioButton)
  // @Do something..
else if(iDontKnowWhat == EditText)
  // @Do Something..
```

Can I implement it?
Please help me sir :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `==` (equals), that actually compares the values, not the objects. Use `instanceof` and check the view like this

---

`if(view instanceof TextView){
      //TODO your logic
}elseif(....`

Answer (score 1):

**use like this ......**

```
  if (iDontKnowWhat instanceof RadioButton)
               //do somethings
      else if (iDontKnowWhat instanceof EditText)
               //do somethings
      else if (iDontKnowWhat instanceof TextView)
               //do somethings
```

**may be this help you ...**